# accessing nested dictionary from api in swift

Tags: swift, option-type

Holy cow...there *MUST* be a better way to access `formatted` in

```
floorplan_summary: {
    bedrooms: {
        low: 1,
        high: 2,
        formatted: "1 - 2 Beds"
    }
}
```

than doing this:

```
    if data["floorplan_summary"]?["bedrooms"] != nil {
        let bedrooms = data["floorplan_summary"]?["bedrooms"] as NSDictionary
        if bedrooms["formatted"] != nil{
            self.beds = bedrooms["formatted"] as String
        }
    }
```

I want to just do this:

```
self.beds = data["floorplan_summary"]?["bedrooms"]?["formatted"] as String
```

..but at each level the object seems to be cast as `AnyObject`.  Why can the compiler assume this `data["floorplan_summary"]?["bedrooms"]` but not the above?

How can I simplify this?

Comment: What about calling `data.valueForKeyPath("floorplan_summary.bedrooms.formatted")`?

Comment: YES.  ^ That.  Please make that an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming `data` is `NSDictionary`, or `[String:AnyObject]`. You can:

```
let beds = data["floorplan_summary"]?["bedrooms"]??["formatted"] as? String // -> as String?
                                                  ^
```

You need extra `?` because `data["floorplan_summary"]?["bedrooms"]` returns `AnyObject??`. You have to unwrap it **twice**.

Why it returns `AnyObject??`? Because `data["floorplan_summary"]?` is `AnyObject`, and `AnyObject` *may or may not* have `subscript`. So, the first `?` means, "If it has `subscript`", and the second means "If `subscript` returns non `nil`".

Comment: wow...that AnyObject?? part took me half day of Googling. Thank you so much.

Comment: I have this dictionary : I tried to access latitude as let restaurantLat = restaurants[indexPath.row]["geometry"]??["location"]?["lat"]? as? Double                                                                           results" : [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 44.1671892,
               "lng" : -93.9568122
            }

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting the syntax you described, I'd suggest using [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON).  It seems pretty popular, and it's all implemented in a single swift file so not hard to add it to your project.  It would look something like this.

```
let floorPlanSummary = JSON(data: yourRawData)
self.beds = floorPlanSummery["bedrooms"]["formatted"].string
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to just invoke `data.valueForKeyPath("floorplan_summary.bedrooms.formatted")`