# Nested Swift Dictionaries and Arrays like a Hash Perl

Tags: arrays, swift, dictionary, scripting

I'm having a horrible time understanding a few things about Swift.

I am attempting to do scripting in Swift to see if it might be useful. One of the major runs of scripting file is how easy the language gets data in from text-files and the hash/dictionary/array parsing syntax.

In trying to parse huge csv files, I'm trying to create a matrix  Dictionary that mimics a perl method `${$hash}{$var1}{$var2}{$var3} = $value;` where `#house_hash` is the actual `hash` and each of the keys are dynamically created and added if not present already.

in ObjectiveC, this was simple enough, using `NSMutableDictionary`, atleast the retrieval part of it.

Swift seems pretty exciting, i wonder with how much ease can this be done?

Till now, all I have is:

```
     var hash = [Int : [Int : [String : AnyObject]]] ()

    let number = hash[var1]?[var2]?["var3"]? .hashValue
    var d3 = [String : AnyObject]()
    var d2 =  [Int : [String : AnyObject]] ()
    d3["var3"] = var3  //var3 is a float

    if(number == nil)
    {
        d2[var2] = d3
        hash[var1] = d2

    }
    else
    {
        hash[var1]![var2] = d3

    }
```

Absolutely no idea what I'm doing. There are no good examples if this dynamic nature of Swift dictionaries that house unknown object types (could be arrays, Ints, Strings, another Dictionary)..

**UPDATE**: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465390/accessing-nested-dictionary-from-api-in-swift) SO answer. But it does not seem to work in Swift Playground.

Comment: If you want something to hold 'unknown' types in a collection that include both object (e.g. `Dictionary`) and non-object types (eg. `Int`), then you need to use `Any` rather than `AnyObject` - see: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID342

Comment: You are right, Did change it Any